# How to print the pattern matching line using awk command along with that i need to print next line with another pattern match

Tags: unix

My file is like this:

```
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.43]
Received client request: List database locks (from user [usernme@mailid.com)
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.221.43]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.43]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.43]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Received client request: List database locks (from user [usernme@mailid.com)
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
```

When search for setting application,it has to print setting application and if next line has ip address it has to print next line
 `Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.43]` otherwise it has to print only setting application line.

my output is below:

```
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.43]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.43]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.43]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
```

please help me how to write the unix code for this

Comment: You might find it easier to detect "Received client request" and delete that line... (grep -v for example) just a thought

Comment: awk -F"|" '$1 ~ "setting" {s=$0;f=1;next} f && $2 ~ "connected" {print s RS$0;f=0}' sampledata.txt

Comment: Ok, why doesn't this command do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with sed. Consider the following:

```
 [ test $] cat test.in                                                      
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]                
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.43]
Received client request: List database locks (from user [usernme@mailid.com)
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.221.43]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.43]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.43]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Received client request: List database locks (from user [usernme@mailid.com)
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.44]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.45]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Received client request: List database locks (from user [usernme@mailid.com)
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Received client request: List database locks (from user [usernme@mailid.com)
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.46]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Received client request: List database locks (from user [usernme@mailid.com)
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Received client request: List database locks (from user [usernme@mailid.com)
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Received client request: List database locks (from user [usernme@mailid.com)
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.47]


 [ test $]
 [ test $]
```

the following sed programme:

```
 [ test $] cat test.sed
#!/bin/sed  -nf

/Setting application/{
         N;
         /ffff:[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/{p;d};
         /\nSetting application/!{
                      s|\n.*||;p;d;
        }
        P;D
}
```

gives this output:

```
 [ test $] ./test.sed test.in
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.43]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.43]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.43]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.44]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.45]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.46]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Setting application AAA active for user [usernme@mailid.com]
Connected from [::ffff:161.179.445.47]
 [ test $]
```

If you want an explanation, or this doesn't do what you want, post back. Please don't forget to rate the answer.

btw, I'm running this on centos 6:

```
[ test $] sed --version
GNU sed version 4.2.1
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE,
to the extent permitted by law.

GNU sed home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-gnu-utils@gnu.org>.
Be sure to include the word ``sed'' somewhere in the ``Subject:'' field.
 [ test $]
```

edit:

```
#!/bin/sed  -nf

/Setting application/{ # match this string
         N; # pull in the next line
         /ffff:[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/{p;d}; # if it contains an ip address print and restart processing
         /\nSetting application/!{ 
                # otherwise check it doesn't contain this text
                      s|\n.*||;p;d;# if not, remove the 2nd line, print and restart processing
        }
        P;D # else print then delete only the first part, then restart processing on the next line.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you pls explain me your code pls?

Comment: Ok. Can you accept my answer if it does what you want? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/Setting application/{print; k=1; next}; k && /Connected from/; {k=0}' input-file
```

or, slightly more elegant:

```
awk 'k && /Connected from/; k=/Setting application/' input-file
```